# Анимированный переход между активити xml

Tags: android

Мне нужно сделать анимированный переход между активити.

У меня всё работает, но хочется разнообразия.

В данный момент у меня слайд-шоу, хочу попробовать другие варианты, но вот на просторах интернета я почти ничего не нашёл.

Может есть ссылка на примеры xml анимации для активити или может у вас есть что-то,чем вы могли поделиться?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы пробовали сами искать? http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/overridependingtransition.php

Вариантов очень много как на русскоязычном инфополе так и англоязычном

Comment: Я это уже давно прочитал)
Тут дефолтные наборы, которые везде и описываются.
А я говорю о том, что может есть что-то более интересное

Comment: Что значит более интересное? Представили? Реализуйте

Comment: Посмотрите здесь может что нибудь понравится. https://android-arsenal.com/

Comment: @ruslan спасибо,годный портал,не знал раньше о нём

Comment: Рад был помочь )

Comment: @shcherbuk, на будущее - в описании метки [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) более-менее важные и интересные ссылки уже приведены